# Divide a number to date in Excel or Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, excel-formula

Probably a naive question but new to this :

I have a column with 100000 entries having dates from Jan 1, 2018 to August 1, 2019.( repeated entries as well) I want to create a new column wherein I want to divide a number lets say 3500 in such a way that sum(new_column) for a particular day is less than or equal to 3500.

For example lets say 01-01-2018 has 40 entries in the dataset, then 3500 is to be distributed randomly between 40 entries in such a way that the total of these 40 rows is less than or equal to 3500 and it needs to be done for all the dates in the dataset.

Can anyone advise me as to how to achieve that.

**EDIT** : The excel file is [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ABIohOLfUITDOQaLu2WSc083fHqNGn_R)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not the best but may work for you. But because you have 100000 entries, it will probably slow down performance, so use it and paste values, because the solution uses function RANDBETWEEN and it keeps recalculating every time you make a change in a cell.

So I made a data test like this:

[image]

First column ID would be the dates, and second column would be random numbers.

And bottom right corner shows totals, so as you can see, totals for each number sum up 3500.

The formula I've used is:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7;A2)=1;3500;IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2;A2)=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7;A2);3500-SUMIF($A$1:A1;A2;$B$1:B1);IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2;A2)=1;RANDBETWEEN(1;3500);RANDBETWEEN(1;3500-SUMIF($A$1:A1;A2;$B$1:B1)))))
```

And it works pretty good. Just pressing `F9` to recalculate the worksheet, gives random numbers, but all of them sum up 3500 all the time.

[image]

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

**UPDATE:** You need to know that my solution will always force the numbers to sum up 3500. In any case the sum of all values would be **less** than 3500. You'll need to adapt that part. As i said, not my best answer...

**UPDATE 2:** Uploaded a sample file to my Gdrive in case you want to check how it works. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ivW2b0b05WV32HxcLc11gP2JWvdYTa84

Comment: Hello @Foxfire And Burns And Burns, Thank you for so much effort for the same, I have shared my file on drive, can you try to take a look at the same. Link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ABIohOLfUITDOQaLu2WSc083fHqNGn_R

Comment: I've looked at your file, the forrmula works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You will need 2 columns
I to count the number of dates and then one for the values

[image]

Formula in B2 is `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$51,A2)`

Formula in C2 is `=RANDBETWEEN(1,3500/B2)`

Column B is giving the count of repetition for each date

Column C is giving a random number whose sum will be at maximum 3500 for each count

The range in formula in B column is $A$2:$A$51, which you can change according to your data

**EDIT**

For each date in your list you can apply a formula like below

[image]

The formula in D2 is `=SUMIF(B:B,B2,C:C)`

For the difference value for each unique date you can use a pivot and apply the formula on sum of each date like below

[image]

Formula in J2 is `=3500-I2`

Comment: Thank you for your response, quite simplified actually, in addition to it, if I want to create a new column Value_2, which would be computed with the logic that it would be 3500-Value_1 for a particular date. Can you please tell me how to achieve that as well? Thanks.

Comment: The idea is to check how much is left out of 3500 for a particular date in the dataset.

Comment: Apply a pivot table on whole data and sum the values based on the dates and their count, you will get the total sum which you can use to get the result; the formula would be simple 3500 - (the achieved sum)

Comment: But then it would not be the case for all the result. For ex- for date 01-01-2018 we have 2 entries, 01-01-2018 500 , 01-01-2018 600, then the output column would be like 01-01-2018 500 3000, 01-01-2018 600 2400

Comment: It would be great if you could edit your answer for the same.

Comment: This works but the pivot would aggregate the dates. I dont want to aggregate them but to have them in their respective field itsef.

Comment: you can check the formula that is without pivot with only formula (there were two solutions)

Comment: I checked it but then it is providing me the total in the new column... not just the difference for a particular row. Also if you see the row 6 has 3531 which cannot be a possible value as well.

Comment: Here is the google sheets link, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ABIohOLfUITDOQaLu2WSc083fHqNGn_R/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have added a comment on the next column and how the computation needs to be... Thank you for helping me out with the same, it would be great if you could take a look at the google sheet link that I shared. Thanks

Comment: Can you please check the drive link. Thanks

Comment: Add this formula in D2  =3500-SUMIF($A$1:A2,A2,$C$1:C2)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - a little late to the party but this looked like a fun challenge!

The simplest way I could think of is to add a rand() column (then hard code, if required) and then another column which calculates the 3500 split per date, based on the rand() column.

Here's the function:
=ROUNDDOWN(3500*B2/SUMIF($A$2:$A$100000,A2,$B$2:$B$100000),0)

Illustrated here:
[image]